# using dynamic_cast to point to other derived class object

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-cast

I have the following scenario. There are two Base classes: Base1, Base2 and two derived classes: Derived, sysCommandExecutor which are derived as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base1 { virtual void dummy() {} };
class Base2 { virtual void dumy() {} };
class Derived: virtual public Base1, public Base2
{ int a; };

class sysCommandExecutor : public Base2
{
public:
int b;
Base1 *ptr;
void func(void);
};

void sysCommandExecutor::func(void)
{
  Derived *d;
  d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(ptr);
  if (d == NULL)
  std::cout << "This is NULL" << std::endl;
  else
  {
  // Call a function of Derived class
  }
}

int main () {
   try {
   sysCommandExecutor * sys =  new sysCommandExecutor;
   sys->func();
   return 0;
   }
}
```

I want to call this function of "Derived" class inside func but the dynamic_cast fails.
I cannot create the function in the sysCommandExecutor class as that is someone else's code.
How to make the ptr pointer in sysCommandExecutor class to point to Derived class object??

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is assinged to ptr? in your code it is an uninitialized pointer

Comment: The code looks odd. Does not seem like proper use of polymorphism. You have a derived class pointer to same instance.

Comment: http://codepad.org/f65rqtYq `No errors or program output.`

Comment: 1) There are no methods in Derived. 2) `ptr` is uninitialized. 3) There is no need for `new` here (let alone a leak).

Comment: Also, beware of a design flaw because `Base1 *ptr` is NOT necessarily referencing a `Derived` object.  Usually polymorphism will work the opposite direction, a `Derived* d` would cast to a `Base1 *` or `Base2* ` rather than the other way around.    

Consider, all Chevys are cars, but not all cars are Chevys.  You are likely attempting the equivalent of casting a Ford to a Chevy.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing an uninitialized pointer `ptr`

if i change main to:

```
int main () {
   sysCommandExecutor * sys =  new sysCommandExecutor;
   sys->ptr=new Derived;
   sys->func();
   delete dynamic_cast<Derived *>(sys->ptr);
   delete sys;
   return 0;

}
```

it works

you are missing a virtual dtor as well